# How can I identify least cloudy image in Google Earth engine?

Tags: image, landsat-8, google-earth-engine

I need to Load Landsat 8 TOA images, get the least cloudy 2015 image.
Search engine shows several images.

How can I identify least cloudy image?

Answer (score 2):

You can sort images using `"CLOUD_COVER"` metadata feature. The "*least cloudly*" images will be added as layer:

```
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA");

var sorted = imageCollection.filterDate('2015-01-01','2015-12-31').sort("CLOUD_COVER",false);

Map.addLayer(sorted, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],max: 0.6},'toa reflectance');
```